# In Firewatir, how can I interact with the Firefox print dialog?

Tags: ruby, firefox, rspec, watir, firewatir

I'm trying to test a page that has the print dialog appear immediately upon accessing it. All I need to do is close the dialog or click Cancel on it so I can interact with the page behind it. I've tried to figure out how to do this, but everything I've found indicates that it isn't possible in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on MacOS or Linux, not sure what to tell you...I bet it's possible, but I need to learn how myself. :)

If you're on Windows, I do have some suggestions.  I suggest checking out the RAutomation gem, which is good for tasks like this (locating and clicking Cancel in the Firefox Print dialog):

https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation

Or you can try using AutoIt.  Installing Watir also installs a copy of AutoItX3.dll, which you can use for simple GUI automation like this.

To see if AutoIt is ready to use on your system, try this out in irb - this code will wait 10 seconds for the Firefox Print dialog to appear, then click the Cancel button:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'win32ole'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> autoit = WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')
=> #<WIN32OLE:0x3c61ce0>
irb(main):003:0> result = autoit.WinWaitActive('Print', '', 10)
=> 1
irb(main):004:0> result = autoit.ControlClick('Print', '', 'Cancel')
=> 1
```

If the "WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')" line raises an exception, you may need to use regsvr32.exe to register the DLL.  For example, here's how to do that on Win7:

- Start an elevated cmd.exe
- regsvr32 C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\watir-1.6.5\lib\watir\AutoItX3.dll

(Note that you might need to change the path above if your Ruby installation is not in C:\Ruby187 or you have a different Watir version than 1.6.5.)

AutoIt documentation is here:

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/

One last thing to watch out for:

If the statement in your code that brings up the Print dialog blocks until the dialog is closed, things get a little more complex.  You'll need to use threads or an external process to handle the dialog (since I don't think FireWatir has a click_no_wait method yet).